# Valid way to hide QLPreviewController RightBarButtonItem/RightBarButtonItems Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios8, xamarin.ios, qlpreviewcontroller, navigationitem

My app supports iOS8+ devices. I want to hide right Action button from navigation bar. By research I found following few workarounds:

***1.*** Create Sub class of QLPreviewController and in ViewDidAppear SetRightBarButtonItems to zero.

```
public class PdfViewController : QLPreviewController
{
  public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear (animated);
        NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems (new UIKit.UIBarButtonItem[0], false);
    }
}
```

In this case problem is RightBarButtonItem appears and then disappears. In mean while user is able to click on that RightBarButtonItem button. I don't want this behavior.

***2.*** Create UIViewController and add QLPreviewController as child ViewController.

void BtnShowPdf_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e) {

```
    var dummyVC = new UIViewController ();
    var pdfVC = new PdfViewController ();

    dummyVC.AddChildViewController (pdfVC);
    dummyVC.View.AddSubview (pdfVC.View);
    dummyVC.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems (new UIBarButtonItem[0], false);

    dummyVC.EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
    dummyVC.AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
    dummyVC.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

    pdfVC.EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
    pdfVC.AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
    pdfVC.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
}
```

In this case If I set QLPreviewController it works as expected. But NavigationBar becomes more darker than default ViewController background color.

Dark Bar:
http://screencast.com/t/bqVMv5qqGz

Needed clear background bar like:
http://screencast.com/t/MUwE2VnxJ7

> My questions are:
>
> A) I would like to know which is the correct way to hide right
>   navigation bar button as per Apple guidelines ? If you have correct
>   solution then those are also appreciated.
>
> B) Also Can you please suggest solution(s) for #1 Or #2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can do this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = nil
    }
```